# How to serve millions of image in wwwroot folder using dotnet core 5?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, asp.net-mvc

#### background

I am using dotnet core 5.
I have million of image in wwwroot folder.
I add wwwroot folder to DefaultItemExcludes of *.csproj

```
<DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);
    wwwroot\defectImage\**;
    </DefaultItemExcludes>
```

It works great in developing.

#### Problem

I deploy it to linux with mounting multiple external NAS to wwwroot folder, like below:

```
wwwroot\defectImage
|_projectA
|_projectB
|__20230301
|___0001.jpg
|___0002.jpg
|___0003.jpg
|___...
|__20230302
|__20230303
|__...
|_projectC
...
```

But in Production, the program initialize very slow (minimum about 20 mins)

What should I do?

#### What I have tried

I try to remove the mount folder, and it initialize very quickly (1 min).
I confirm the performance issue is because there are too many image in wwwroot.
I also try search the issue on google and stackOverFlow, and found nothing

#### Code usage:

when frontend send a http request about a image to my controller, it found the image in wwwRoot and return.
For example:

```
public IActionResult Get(string projectName, string dateTime, string 
fileName){
  // combine the parameter to generate img path
  string imgPath = "wwwroot/...";
  return File(imgPath, "image/bmp");
  // or return PhysicalFile(imgPath, "image/jpg");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a different path? Other than wwwroot?

Comment: What is your code doing with the files? If you loop over all of them it will take really long for sure

Comment: @Jonathan, when frontend send a http request about a image to my controller, it found the image in wwwRoot and return

Comment: @Fildor, no, wwwroot is the defulat path for static file in dotnet core. Where shoud I try to put the file?

Comment: You have a couple performance limiting challenges here.  Mounting files from the NAS == network.  That many files can cause issues too. Even a simple `ls` will take forever (or just fail on too many inputs under certain cases).  I have seen systems split these LARGE directories into sub-directories using dates or the letters of the flienames to make the final directory less immense.

Comment: @Nic3500, thanks you, this is a good direction to solve the problem. I dont think dotnet would loop the image files, because I give the direct image path to return the image file.

Comment: Why not use a static file handler?

Comment: @DanielA.White, because there are escape character in the name of some image files., eg: "001#ABC.jpg", the url "hostname/image/001#ABC.jpg" will not work, because the browser would not sent the part of url after the hash sign.

Comment: Ensure the client is percent encoding that then

Comment: @DanielA.White, thanks for your advice. I would give it a try. If I change the way I get image, the image file still be placed in wwwroot, thus it should initialize very slow like the current situation.

Comment: @Fildor, I try to create a MyStaticFiles folder to place my image based on this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0#serve-static-files-1, it still initiate slowly

Comment: I'd try adding `wwwroot/defectImage` rather than `wwwroot\defectImage\**`.

Comment: @Armali, thanks for your response. I removed the "**", and it slowed the initialization even in my dev env. I also tried using `wwwroot/defectImage/**` rather than `wwwroot\defectImage\**`,  it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I end up using nginx to serve static content, such as images.
Using rewrite directive of nginx to minimize the modification of code.